# How to get a limited number of values from a HashMap or LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Say I have a `LinkedHashMap` containing 216 entries, how would I get the first 100 values (here, of type `Object`) from a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object>`.

Comment: Do you want the values (as in your question/title) or the records (key:value pairs, as in your statement)?

Comment: Ok, thought so. Thanks, then see my answer (or others). I rewrote your question a bit for clarity then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ugly One-Liner

This **ugly one-liner** would do (and return a `ArrayList<Object>` in the question's case):

```
Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(lhMap.values())).subList(0, 100)
```

This would work for a `HashMap` as well, however `HashMap` being backed by a `HashSet` there's not guarantee that you will get the first 100 values that were entered; it would work on other types, with similar limitations.

**Notes:**

- relatively unefficient (read the Javadoc to know why - though there's worse!),
- careful when using views (read the Javadoc to know more),
- I did mention it was ugly.

## Step-By-Step Usage Example

*(as per the OP's comment)*

```
Map<Integer, Pair<Double, SelectedRoad>> hashmap3 =
  new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Pair<Double, SelectedRoad>>();

// [...] add 216 elements to hasmap3 here somehow

ArrayList<Pair<Double,SelectedRoad>> firstPairs = 
  Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(hashmap3.values())).subList(0, 100)

// you can then view your Pairs' SelectedRow values with them with:
//  (assuming that:
//    - your Pair class comes from Apache Commons Lang 3.0
//    - your SelectedRoad class implements a decent toString() )
for (final Pair<Double, SelectedRoad> p : firstPairs) {
    System.out.println("double: " + p.left);
    System.out.println("road  : " + p.right);
}
```

Comment: I have  Map<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> > hashmap3 = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> >();         Now I need just 100 rows from it. Please write code. Thanks!

Comment: Just substitute `Pair<Double, SelectedRoad>` with the `Object` in the code sample above. You'll get a `List<Pair<Double, SelectedRoad>>` of 100 elements.

Comment: you means                                                                             List<Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> > mylist = new ArrayList();
          Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(hashmap3.values())).subList(0, 100);

Comment: @AdnanAliCh: No, that should work as described. What you wrote would not do anything to the ArrayList. You can write this instead: `ArrayList<Pair<Double,SelectedRoad>> firstPairs = Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(hashmap3.values())).subList(0, 100)`.

Comment: @AdnanAliCh: Let us know how that works out for you and accept the answer that best matches your expectations when you are happy with the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your Solution is working for me.....Do you have any improved solution rather then using subList() function..in....Some other good approach to get the same output...Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(hashmap3.values())).subList(0, 100)

Comment: @AdnanAliCh: define "improved". You need to be clearer on what you want from the get-go, or we'll keep going back and forth. This one works, with some caveats pointed out. What else do you want, and what caveats do you want to avoid, or what exact output do you need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found the exact result, which I need.!

Comment: Overall thanks for your SOLUTION! It works fine enough for me!

Answer (score 5):

Well to start with, doing this for `HashMap` as per your title, doesn't make much sense - `HashMap` has no particular order, and the order may change between calls. It makes more sense for `LinkedHashMap` though.

There, I'd use [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/index.html)'s [`Iterables.limit`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) method:

```
Iterable<Object> first100Values = Iterables.limit(map.values(), 100);
```

or

```
// Or whatever type you're interested in...
Iterable<Map.Entry<Integer, Object>> firstEntries =
    Iterables.limit(map.entrySet(), 100);
```

You can then create a list from that, or iterate over it, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: +1 for Guava, I thought of that one straight away but I assumed that wasn't desired here, for some reason. Sefinitely better - in so many ways - than my ugly line, and even shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
Map<Integer, Object> records;
List<Entry<Integer, Object>> firstHundredRecords
    = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Object>>(records.entrySet()).subList(0, 100);
```

Although note that this will copy all the entries from the map.

Comment: Copying 100 object references is not that expensive. Like it.

Comment: It'll actually copy 216 references. But still, that's not that expensive.

Comment: Ah - yes - sublist is called on the new list, that has received the entire entry set. TooManyBracketsConfusionError ;)

Answer (score 3):

To copy only the records you need with using a library.

```
Map<Integer, Object> records;

List<Entry<Integer, Object>> firstHundredRecords = new ArrayList<>();
for(Entry<Integer, Object> entry : records.entrySet()) {
    firstHundredRecords.add(entry);
    if (firstHundredRecords.size()>=100) break;
}
```

Comment: Map<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> > hashmap3 = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> >();
      List<Entry<Integer, Object>> firstHundredRecords = new ArrayList<>();
for(Entry<Integer, SelectedRoad> entry : hashmap3.entrySet()) {
    firstHundredRecords.add(entry);
    if (firstHundredRecords.size()>=100) break;
}
                                                                 But it not proper for Map<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> > hashmap3 = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad> >();

Comment: You should have `Map<Integer, Pair<Double,SelectedRoad>> entry` Your IDE should be able to auto-correct this for you.

Comment: IDT Auto correct will return this                                      for(Entry<Integer, Pair<Double, SelectedRoad>> entry : hashmap3.entrySet()) {
           
              firstHundredRecords.addAll((Collection<? extends Entry<Integer, SelectedRoad>>) entry);
              
              if (firstHundredRecords.size()>=100) break;
          }

          int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
                System.out.println("value no. "+count +" : "+ firstHundredRecords.get(j).getKey()+":::" + firstHundredRecords.get(j).getValue());
               count++;
            }

Comment: And on execution I have the following Exception                        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Comment: Hello Mr. @Peter Lawrey: I am looking for solution from you.

Comment: And what do you see in a debugger?  This means you have a generic type which is incorrect or you are casting incorrectly. You need to place a break point on the line where this error occurs or trap this exception in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner will return the first 100 values of a map, or all elements if the map has fewer than 100 values.

```java
List<Object> values = map.values().stream().limit(100).toList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use counter. Your foreach loop will exit when your counter reached 100.

Answer (score -2):

Write a loop which uses a `Iterator.next()` 100 times, and then stops.

I was going to say something about `NavigableMap` and `SortedMap` - but their interfaces are defined in terms of keys, not indexes. But they may be useful nevertheless, depending on what your actual underlying problem is.